# Update certain columns of a dataframe dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
channel name     conv_perc
 FTV_FB_VID       0.038069 
 FB_DISP_VID      0.139276
 FTV_FB_DISP_VID  0.033426
 DISP             0.056639 
 FTV_DISP         0.084494
```

I am looking to split `channel name` on `_` and create as many columns as the tokens in the string, with the same names and update them with corresponding value in `conv_perc`. But, the value in `conv_perc` needs to be first divided by channels in `channel name`and then copied under columns.

My idea of doing this is to compute unique channels and create columns beforehand; then, iterate row by row and copy the value from `conv_perc` into only those columns that are in corresponding `channel name` cell. I'm unable to do it without a loop. I am after a `vectorized` solution.

Expected output:

```
channel name     conv_perc   FTV    FB      VID     DISP   PTV 
 FTV_FB_VID       0.038069  0.0127 0.0127 0.0127     0      0 
 FB_DISP_VID      0.139276  0.     0.0464 0.0464    0.0464  0 
 FTV_FB_DISP_VID  0.033426  0.0084 0.0084 0.0084    0.0084  0
 DISP             0.056639                          0.0566
 FTV_DISP         0.084494  0.0422                  0.0422
```

Please notice the values in FTV and other columns are divided by the resulting length of the tokens when we split `channel name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I beleive you need [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with multiple values by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and divide by `sum` of `1` values:

```
df1 = df['channel name'].str.get_dummies('_')
df1 = df1.mul(df['conv_perc'], axis=0).div(df1.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df1)
       DISP        FB       FTV       VID
0  0.000000  0.012690  0.012690  0.012690
1  0.046425  0.046425  0.000000  0.046425
2  0.008356  0.008356  0.008356  0.008356
3  0.056639  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
4  0.042247  0.000000  0.042247  0.000000
```

If instead `0` need missing values add [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df1 = df['channel name'].str.get_dummies('_')
df1 = df1.mul(df['conv_perc'], axis=0).div(df1.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mask(df1==0)
print (df1)
       DISP        FB       FTV       VID
0       NaN  0.012690  0.012690  0.012690
1  0.046425  0.046425       NaN  0.046425
2  0.008356  0.008356  0.008356  0.008356
3  0.056639       NaN       NaN       NaN
4  0.042247       NaN  0.042247       NaN
```

Then if need append to original use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
      channel name  conv_perc      DISP        FB       FTV       VID
0       FTV_FB_VID   0.038069       NaN  0.012690  0.012690  0.012690
1      FB_DISP_VID   0.139276  0.046425  0.046425       NaN  0.046425
2  FTV_FB_DISP_VID   0.033426  0.008356  0.008356  0.008356  0.008356
3             DISP   0.056639  0.056639       NaN       NaN       NaN
4         FTV_DISP   0.084494  0.042247       NaN  0.042247       NaN
```